# Using RS utility to deploy report using database driven directories

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am trying to use RS utility on my vb.net script to deploy report as I loop through my table that has a list of all the reports, folders, datasources, linked reports, roles and so on.  Is it possible to call RS utility inside VB.net code or add extra libraries to enable sqlconnection in the vb code? I have 2008 R2 sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the **rs Utility**, you don't have many options. From Books Online:

> You do not declare namespaces within the script file. The scripting
>   environment makes several useful Microsoft .NET Framework namespaces
>   available to you: **System.Web.Services**, **System.Web.Services.Protocols**,
>   **System.Xml**, and **System.IO**.

See [Format a Reporting Services Script File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154561.aspx).

So in that sense you can't do anything like reading a table from a database, if that's your intention. You could read a config file perhaps, but these is no real option to extend the Utility's functionality.

Your only other alternative would be to interact with the Report Server Web Service directly in you own code and not use the **rs Utility**.